# Gaussian approximation of Landau Ginzburg and Renoramalization Group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, renormalization, ising-model, effective-field-theory

I am studing an introduction to the Renormalization Group (RG); during my course my prof. came up saying that:
Landau-Ginzburg (LG) theory truncated at Gaussian order is exact at the critical point.

Some fact: If we talk about 2nd order phase transition i can accept it: at a 2nd order phase transition point (a particular fixed point of the RG) only 1 coupling is relevant;

If we take the Ising examplewith B=0 (tuned) only 1 coupling (or interchangebly the relative scaling field) is RELEVANT, it is $t_1 = (T-T_c)/T_c$.

On the other hand I write the LG free energy truncated at the gaussian order, in the proximity of a fixed point ($m(x)\simeq m_0+\mathcal{\delta}m(x)$) it is:

$H(m(x))=e^{H(m_0)}+\int d^Dx \frac{1}{2}(\nabla \mathcal{\delta}m(x))^2 + a (\mathcal{\delta}m(x))^2$

here $a=(\frac{T-T_c}{2})+\frac{v6}{4!}$.
Here We can see that the ONLY RELEVANT COUPLING $t_1$ appears as the coefficient of the term ($\mathcal{\delta}m(x))^2$.
What i understood :

1: for 2nd order phase transition 1 coupling is relevant and the LG theory takes this relevant coupling into account (but it won't predict the right physics in $D\leq4$ out of the critical point for sure); what happens at the critical point?

2:if i take the LG hamiltonian in the most general case (with all irrelevant couplings turned on) and iterate some renormalization group transformations all the irrelevant couplings will disappear, while relevant couplings "increases".

This means that i can reach (under RG flow) a theory (starting from a general LG theory) with only the coupling $t_1$ turned on (so we are actually at the Gaussian order); then at the critical point $t_1=0$ and we are left with a free theory that we can solve exactly.
Is this the right interpretation ?

What if we are not dealing with 2nd order phase transitions ? what if the relevant coupling are 2 ? in that case i cannot understand.

Any clarification of the question is welcome and also suggestion on where to find info.

Excuse if my understanding of the question is very naive, i am just getting started :)

Comment: You can not describe the Ising transition in $D<4$ with just the Gaussian theory. The critical theory is an interacting one.

Comment: excuse me, i should have write $D< 4$ ( in D=4 mean field, Landau-Ginzburg at gaussian order give the same critical exponents and the theory works); but what happens in $D<4$? you wrote that at the critical point the theory is interacting. do you agree with $t_1=0$ at the critical point ? i cannot understand why is wrong to say then that we are left with a free theory.

Comment: You need to add the $m^4$ term.

Comment: ok thank you, i had some time to think about it. I would like just to ask if is pacific to say that, at the critical point the gaussian approximation is exact for $D\geq4$, because the only relevant coupling ($t_1$) goes to zero ? (role of fluctuation in D=4 or higher is irrelevant at the critical point)

Comment: Yes, for $D\geq 4$, the $t_1$ is the only relevant coupling, and $m^4$ is irrelevant.

Comment: thank you for the precise answers